# Error when creating a new Laravel project on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I successfully installed Composer and Laravel in my shared hosting.
Then when I want to create a new Laravel project

```
laravel new myproject
```

It gives me

> Crafting application...
>       Could not open input file: composer.phar
>       Application ready! Build something amazing.

Based on internet research, I edited my `.bash_profile` and added

```
alias composer="php ~/composer.phar"
```

then I run

```
source .bash_profile
```

Now I can type `composer` in the command prompt successfully.
But I still receive the same error when I run `laravel new myproject`

I don't have access to move the `composer.phar` to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Might be it is belonging to server hosting it is not the problem of laravel or composer. Might be the user of your server do not have access on server. Have a word with your hosting provider about this.

Comment: can you be more specific as in do not have access on certain folder or something maybe ? i can access the server via ssh
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to install composer via 'sudo' command?

Comment: @imRcH He probably has no `sudo` privileges on a shared hosting.

Comment: yes i don't have sudo privileges